# Curve with second derivative identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just solved the following exercise:

Let $I = (a,b)$ be an open interval, $a,b$ possibly equal to $\pm \infty$ and $\alpha: I \to \mathbb R^3$ a smooth parametrized curve that has the property that $\alpha ''(t)$ is identically $0$. What can be said about $\alpha$?

My answer: If $\alpha'' = 0$ then $\alpha'$, the velocity, is constant and then the movement $\alpha (t)$ is a line in $\mathbb R^3$.

Could anyone tell me please if my answer is correct and also, if it is everything that can be said about $\alpha$ or if there is anything else?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: And there is nothing else that can be said about the curve?